# Problem with change PostgreSQL data drive

Tags: database, postgresql

I want change drive where I keep my data of postgresql on VPS server with Ubuntu 18.04.

Now it's default:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'
```

on /dev/sda. I want keep this on /dev/sdb. I have created partition /dev/sdb1 properly.

I find tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-postgresql-data-folder-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

I did the same steps like above, means:

1. Stop postgresql process
2. Copy all data from /var/lib/postgresql to my second drive to /second_drive/postgresql_data
3. Change 'data_directory' in my postgresql.conf
4. Start postgresql - and here I have problem. DB doesn't starting. I don't remember error, and I can't check this now because my db have to working whole weekend.

Anyone has a idea what's causes problem? Something another to change too? I looking info in google, but all tuts looking like than above.

EDIT:

I remembered that the problem was with the permissions for postgres user.

I tried now again change the permissions for directory with data, but chown not working - I mean, terminal not return any error/message, but the permissions/ownership not change. I find info that's problem is because I tried change permissions on mounted drive, but it's not possible on NTFS drives. I'm confused about that. My current data is on /dev/md3 to /disk_ssd_3

I putting info from my linux below:

/etc/fstab - I don't know where is my /disk_ssd_3

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md3        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md2        /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/nvme0n1p4  swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/nvme1n1p4  swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
UUID=E368-416A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       0
```

lsblk

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part  /disk_hdd_1
sdb           8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0   1.8T  0 part  /disk_hdd_2
nvme1n1     259:0    0 419.2G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1 259:6    0 419.2G  0 part  /disk_ssd_3
nvme0n1     259:1    0 419.2G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   511M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0   511M  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 417.7G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0 417.7G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:5    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
```

Comment: That should work in principle. But without an error message we cannot help.

Comment: Hard to guess without the exact error message as @LaurenzAlbe correctly said. First thing I'd check is if the postgres user is the owner of the /second_drive/postgresql_data directory and has the appropriate permissions

Comment: @cogitoergosum, exactly! I remembered that's problem. I edited my post.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).